# Turn off Source Checksum Check Yocto

Tags: linux, checksum, yocto

Where do I specify
`BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM = "0"`
in Yocto to disable checksum check of source code?

I get:

```
ERROR: No checksum specified for /PATH/TO/ti-linux-kernel.git, please add at least one to the     recipe:
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "e8e287fd725bea8b4220ebe9094cda86"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "4a4f522b05e6c1fcd1872f2fc7c82061dfdc4a19c5f866858005daa198f89bbb"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see a variable named BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM in the Yocto documentation.

As far as I can tell, you shouldn't need to specify the `SRC_URI[...]` checksums for a git repository. In your bitbake recipe, does `/PATH/TO/ti-linux-kernel.git` have a `git://` at the front of it? Bitbake uses that to determine the type of SCM tool to use. If you want to access a git repo via http you would specify

```
SRC_URI = "git://server.com/PATH/TO/ti-linux-kernel.git;protocol=http"
```

Maddeningly, this is only hinted at in documentation for [SRC_URI](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.4/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI).

The SRC_URI[md5sum] and SRC_URI[sha256sum] are instead intended for ensuring downloaded tarballs are the same as when you write the recipe. If you were adding a tarball (say, `http://server.com/path/to/some-project.tar.gz`), the [recommended](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#new-recipe-fetching-code) way is to

> ... comment the statements out and then attempt to build the software. The build will produce an error for each missing checksum and as part of the error message provide the correct checksum string. Once you have the correct checksums, simply copy them into your recipe for a subsequent build.

You can see in your error message that in this case they have indeed been provided.

Answer (score 18):

Regarding [this](http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/bitbake-devel/2014-October/005090.html) page `BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM` is a variable which can be used in .bb files. So, you can simply add the following line to the corresponding .bb file, which your `SRC_URI` has been set in it, to avoid the checksum checking error:

```
BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM = "0"
```

By adding this line the checksum check error (saying: No checksum specified for blah/blah/blah, please add at least one to the recipe OR the other error saying: Missing `SRC_URI` checksum) won't break the compile process anymore and just a warning will be thrown.

Hope it helps

Comment: This works. Instead of errors bitbake throws warnings (the checksums are still printed if you want to go back and secure your *successful* build).

Comment: This should be the real answer IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If your cloning the repo with **https:**//some_path you will need

```
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "e8e287fd725bea8b4220ebe9094cda86"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = " 4a4f522b05e6c1fcd1872f2fc7c82061dfdc4a19c5f866858005daa198f89bbb"
```

while you clone the repo with **git:**//some_path you will need 
md5sum of any other file like

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=a77c327d4d1da3707d42dde9725d4769"
```

Comment: No, that's wrong. It doesn't matter if you're using git, https, http, or ssh as the transport protocol; while cloning a repo, you don't need to specify a SRC_URI checksum.

Comment: @Anders Instead, I experienced that by changing the protocol from git to https, it started giving me this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> ```
>  BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM:forcevariable = "0"
> ```

In `conf/local.conf` inside `build` directory or in any other configuration metadata files e.g. `site.conf` or `auto.conf`

`forcevariable` is highest order override which will ensure that it will not entertain other settings of this variable found in other places e.g. in `meta/conf/distro/include/default-distrovars.inc`