# GIT errors during Yocto build by Bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake, quilt

I'm trying to build a image for IMX8MP SolidRun board (Hummingboard Mate board) but I'm going crazy with this. I'm using this git page:

https://github.com/SolidRun/meta-solidrun-arm-imx8

With this repo:

```
repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-hardknott -m imx-5.10.72-2.2.0.xml
```

But I have tried with this repo too:

```
repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-hardknott -m imx-5.10.72-2.2.2.xml
```

These are the errors I get with different configurations:

FIRST ONE:

ERROR: tinycompress-1.1.6-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL:

> 'git://git.alsa-project.org/tinycompress.git;protocol=git;branch=master'.
> Unable to fetch URL from any source. ERROR: Logfile of failure stored
> in:
> /home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tinycompress/1.1.6-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.21811
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/holoh/yocto/sources/meta-imx/meta-sdk/recipes-multimedia/tinycompress/tinycompress_1.1.6.bb:do_fetch)
> failed with exit code '1'

CHANGING URL configuration on yocto/sources/meta-imx/meta-sdk/recipes-multimedia/tinycompress/tinycompress_1.1.6.bb because firewall could be acting.( to  https://github.com/alsa-project/tinycompress.git adding protocol=https), the error I have received is this:

> ERROR: tinycompress-1.1.6-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL:
> 'https://github.com/alsa-project/tinycompress.git;protocol=https;branch=master'.
> Missing SRC_URI checksum ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
> /home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tinycompress/1.1.6-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.10927
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/holoh/yocto/sources/meta-imx/meta-sdk/recipes-multimedia/tinycompress/tinycompress_1.1.6.bb:do_fetch)
> failed with exit code '1'

I add checksum line as I can read here ([Turn off Source Checksum Check Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501692/turn-off-source-checksum-check-yocto)). Two solutions tried, same result:

> ERROR: tinycompress-1.1.6-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc
> /home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tinycompress/1.1.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc
> push' exited with 0  Output: stdout: Applying patch
> 0001-tinycompress-Add-id3-decoding.patch patching file
> include/tinycompress/id3_tag_decode.h can't find file to patch at
> input line 224 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? The
> text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/src/utils/Makefile.am b/src/utils/Makefile.am |index 1b996d4..e813689 100644 |---
> a/src/utils/Makefile.am |+++ b/src/utils/Makefile.am
> -------------------------- No file to patch.  Skipping patch. 1 out of 1 hunk ignored can't find file to patch at input line 236 Perhaps you
> used the wrong -p or --strip option? The text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/src/utils/cplay.c b/src/utils/cplay.c |index 87863a3..2a52b52 100644 |---
> a/src/utils/cplay.c |+++ b/src/utils/cplay.c
> -------------------------- No file to patch.  Skipping patch. 3 out of 3 hunks ignored patching file src/utils/id3_tag_decode.c Patch
> 0001-tinycompress-Add-id3-decoding.patch does not apply (enforce with
> -f)
>
> stderr: ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
> /home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tinycompress/1.1.6-r0/temp/log.do_patch.22146
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/holoh/yocto/sources/meta-imx/meta-sdk/recipes-multimedia/tinycompress/tinycompress_1.1.6.bb:do_patch)
> failed with exit code '1'

What is going on here? I don't understand why It doesn't work, I'm following only the steps and this sh*t is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have a proxy i guess. Try to disable it.
I tested it works fine.

Comment: If I try the repositories with git command, all works fine. I'm not using a proxy. I will check it, but I think I don't have any proxy.

Comment: what are you even trying to bitbake

Comment: I'm doing bitbake imx-image-full, following all the steps in the git url, from that repo, and downloading the imx solidrun layer from hardknott branch, using WSL 18.04.